# setting cookies using php

Tags: php, html, cookies

```
<?php   
$_SESSION['name'] = array($_POST['name']) ;
$n = $_SESSION['name'][0];
setcookie('name[0]',$n,time()+(60*30));
?>
<html>
    <form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="step-3.php" >
        <input class="input100" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Your First Name " value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['name[0]']; ?>"  />
        <button class="contact100-form-btn" type="submit" formmethod="post" onclick="valid()">
            Next
        </button>
    </form>
</html>
```

I need to set `COOKIE` so as to retain the data in the form in case the user clicks the browser's back button from the the action page.

But somehow the cookie is unable to set. The error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name[0]

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I need to save the data as an array 
also suggest if there is a better way to do his. maybe using session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: At what line is that error showing up?

Comment: Also what is the contents of the $_POST?

Comment: @Andreas the error shows up at this line: `<input class="input100" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Your First Name " value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['name[0]']; ?>"  />`

Comment: the content of `$_POST` is a string

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not started, thus the session array is not accessible.

Add `session_start();` as the line below the PHP tag and it should work.

Comment: i have a `session_start()`. i have only given the neccessary lines of code.

Comment: That is generally a necessary line of code for us to know how to help you.

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar what do you get when you do `var_dump($_SESSION]`?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i get all the session data. no error there.